# What is the minimal value of $A \cup B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\frac {|A-B|}{15} = \frac {|B-A|}{10} = \frac {|A\cap B|}{6}$$

- What is the minimal value of $A \cup B$?

This question is from my exam. I've tried to solve it by giving values and added them up.

Regards

Comment: If that's the actual question it's of course $0$ as there's nothing stating that $A$ and $B$ can't both be the empty set...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that: $$|A \cup B| = |A-B| + |B-A | + |A \cap B|$$

If we have: $$\frac{|A-B|}{15}=\frac{|B-A|}{10}=\frac{|A \cap B|}{6}= k$$ we will get: $$|A \cup B| = 15k+10k+6k = 31k$$ Can $k$ be $\leq 0$?

Comment: I knew it. The thing I cannot get is $\frac {|A-B|}{15} = \frac {|B-A|}{10} = \frac {|A\cap B|}{6}$

Comment: Got it now. Should we make them equal to $k$?

Comment: $k$ could be $0$, right?

Comment: @ziggurism As the question is stated yes, if $A=B=\emptyset$ you will get that...

Comment: @skyking $A$ and $B$ are different from null set.

Comment: @Busi The question doesn't say that so how is one supposed to know that?

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying with $30$ gives $2|A-B|=3|B-A|=5|A\cap B|$, which implies that |A-B| must be divisible by 3 and by 5 and therefore by $15$.